# Cannot connect to the MySQL Swsscom service on hostcenter.com

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I created a MySQL database by logging into the site *phpmyadmin.hostcenter.com* and then tried to connect to is using ODBC (from Windows 10). I first used *MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver* and then the *MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver*. 
In both cases, the ODBC log file indicated an error with *SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT*; so I suppose that I either have not the right server name or that I have not been authorised to access the server.
I use the following ODBC MySQL information (adapted to be somewhat secured):

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
SERVER=testdatabase-205543.mysql.hostcenter.com
DATABASE=205543-testdatabase
UID=205543_gb97446;
PWD=************
```

I would really appreciate if somebody can help me setting up either my rights or my ODBC information correctly (or both) for this Swisscom service.

Comment: Connecting to a database over the internet unencrypted is a security nightmare. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Today I got an answer from the SwissCom help desk stating that access to databases from outside is not allowed for security reasons and that access is only possible from inside the Hostcenter environment.
Thanks to anybody who spared some thoughts about this issue.